# How do I get an object at a memory location?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, pointers, struct

If I have the memory location of something stored in an integer how can I get the object stored at the memory location?

How I need to use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CelGL.h"

/*
 Stride: The size of the data structure containing the per-vertex data
 Offset: Offset within the structure to find this data
 */

// Example structs that store the data
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} Vertex;

typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} Normal;

typedef struct {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
} Color;

// Info for rendering
typedef struct {
    int vertex;
    int vertexStride;
    int vertexOffset;
    int normal;
    int normalStride;
    int normalOffset;
    int index;
} RenderData;


RenderData _renderData;
int _buffer; // Memory location of array with data

// sets the integer to the memory location of the data
void celBindBuffer(int *buffer)
{
    _buffer = &buffer; // Alert:Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'int **'
}

void celVertexAttribPointer(CelVertexAttrib attrib, int stride/*bytes*/, int offset/*bytes*/)
{
    switch (attrib) {
        case CelVertexAttribPosition:
            _renderData.vertex = _buffer;
            _renderData.vertexStride = stride;
            _renderData.vertexOffset = offset;
            break;
        case CelVertexAttribNormal:
            _renderData.normal = _buffer;
            _renderData.normalStride = stride;
            _renderData.normalOffset = offset;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void printVertex(Vertex v)
{
    printf("Vertex[%f,%f,%f]\n", v.x, v.y, v.z);
}

void testPrint(int size/*size in bytes*/)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Gets the initial location of the data in which it is stored, gets the size of the struct and multiplies it by the index and then offsets to the 
        Vertex v = (Vertex)(_renderData.vertex + i * _renderData.vertexStride + _renderData.vertexOffset); // How can I do this?
        printVertex(v);
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to get the object at that location, and why am I getting a warning at `_buffer = &buffer;`?

**EDIT:**
The variable buffer is an array of structs, not just a single value so I need to have the memory location of it. Once I have that, how can I receive the object at that location (Line:`Vertex v = (Vertex)(_renderData.vertex + i * _renderData.vertexStride + _renderData.vertexOffset);`)?

**EDIT:**
So to get the location of the data would I use _buffer = &(*buffer);?

**EDIT**
Information passed onto method:

```
typedef struct {
    Vertex position;
    Normal normal;
} VertexData;

static const VertexData mesh[] = {
    {/*v:*/{-0.000000, -1.125000, 0.000000}, /*n:*/{0.059877, -0.998169, 0.007874} },
    {/*v:*/{-0.000000, -0.986528, -0.475087}, /*n:*/{0.114078, -0.863674, -0.490890} },
    {/*v:*/{0.357184, -0.948670, -0.284845}, /*n:*/{0.427045, -0.850368, -0.307321} },
    {/*v:*/{-0.000000, -1.125000, 0.000000}, /*n:*/{0.059877, -0.998169, 0.007874} },
    {/*v:*/{0.357184, -0.948670, -0.284845}, /*n:*/{0.427045, -0.850368, -0.307321} },
    {/*v:*/{0.449795, -0.958029, 0.102663}, /*n:*/{0.477462, -0.877438, 0.045442} },
    {/*v:*/{-0.000000, -1.125000, 0.000000}, /*n:*/{0.059877, -0.998169, 0.007874} },
    {/*v:*/{0.449795, -0.958029, 0.102663}, /*n:*/{0.477462, -0.877438, 0.045442} },
        ...
};

void render() {
    celBindBuffer(mesh);
    celVertexAttribPointer(CelVertexAttribPosition, sizeof(VertexData), offsetof(VertexData, position));
    testPrint(sizeof(mesh) / sizeof(VertexData));
}
```

Comment: May I ask what reason made you declared `_buffer` and `Renderdata.vertex` as `int` instead of `int *`?

Comment: @tia: Because I don't want to have a regular pointer. I need to store the byte location of the data in the memory so I can manually control the number of bytes changed. For example if a I have a pointer to an int array, then pointer+1 = pointer + 3 bytes. If I have an int that stores the memory location then pointer+1 = pointer + 1 byte.

Comment: So how about using `char *` or `void *` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer (`int *buffer`) is a variable that contains a memory address. Reading the memory at an address pointed by a pointer is called dereferencing a pointer. What you are doing is actually taking an address of the pointer itself. So instead of this:

`_buffer = &buffer;`

.. you have to dereference a pointer to read a value pointed by this `buffer` pointer:

`_buffer = *buffer;`

I recommend you to read [Pointer Basics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/) article, it can help you wrap your head around these things a little bit.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

In your case, you are better off having a pointer of the same type as the object that is being passed in.. Otherwise it is quite a lot confusing. Here is an example of working with that pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} Vertex; /* Just to make a simple code compile.. */
typedef Vertex Normal; /* Same story... */

typedef struct {
    Vertex position;
    Normal normal;
} VertexData;

static const VertexData mesh[] = {
    { {-0.000000, -1.125000, 0.000000}, {0.059877, -0.998169, 0.007874} },
    { {-0.000000, -0.986528, -0.475087}, {0.114078, -0.863674, -0.490890} },
    { {0.357184, -0.948670, -0.284845}, {0.427045, -0.850368, -0.307321} },
    { {-0.000000, -1.125000, 0.000000}, {0.059877, -0.998169, 0.007874} },
    { {0.357184, -0.948670, -0.284845}, {0.427045, -0.850368, -0.307321} },
    { {0.449795, -0.958029, 0.102663}, {0.477462, -0.877438, 0.045442} },
    { {-0.000000, -1.125000, 0.000000}, {0.059877, -0.998169, 0.007874} },
    { {0.449795, -0.958029, 0.102663}, {0.477462, -0.877438, 0.045442} }
};

void celBindBuffer(const VertexData *data)
{
    const Vertex *v0 = &data[0].position;
    const Normal *n0 = &data[0].normal;

    const Vertex *v1 = &data[1].position;
    const Normal *n1 = &data[1].normal;

    printf("Vertex#1: %f/%f/%f...\n", v0->x, v0->y, v0->z);
    printf("Vertex#2: %f/%f/%f...\n", v1->x, v1->y, v1->z);
}

int main(void)
{
    celBindBuffer(mesh);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, a little bit of [pointer arithmetics](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) does the job.
However, there is a bit of a problem with your function - what you are trying to do is to pass an array of `VertexData` objects. But the problem is that function `celBindBuffer()` does not know how many elements are there in that array... You have to pass a number to that function to tells how many elements are there in a vector. Otherwise you can easily run into [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: The variable buffer is an array of structs, not just a single value so I need to have the memory location of it. Once I have that, how can I receive the object at that location (Line:Vertex v = (Vertex)(_renderData.vertex + i * _renderData.vertexStride + _renderData.vertexOffset);)?

Comment: So to get the location of the data would I use _buffer = &(*buffer);?

Comment: Stas, it is hard to answer your question without seeing what exactly is passed to that `celBindBuffer` function.. But the thing is that `buffer` variable is a location of the data. To get it, you need to do nothing. If you want to read values from there - you can dereference it as long as it is a POD type, and even use pointer arithmetics to move over multiple elements pointed by `buffer`. Otherwise you can use `memcpy` to copy memory regions. I guess... you have to clarify you question a bit more to get a better answer...

Comment: I added the information that is being passed in to the method

Comment: @stas: Just updated my answer. Hope it helps. I really think it is worth a couple of hours for you to read some tutorials about pointers and pointer arithmetics in C. It will pay you back big time. Gotta go to sleep now.. it is almost Monday here and I got to get to work early tomorrow :) Good luck!

Comment: BTW, `pointer + 1` is in fact `pointer + sizeof(int)`. It could be `pointer +4` or `pointer + 8`. It depends on the architecture.

Comment: Thanx :). I have read a bunch of tutorials on this but, being used to java I still get confused sometimes. About the pointer + 1, thats what I meant. I have 4 bytes per int on my mac.

Comment: I already know that I can use pointer arithmetic, but I need to be able to do it by pointing to the bytes in the memory.

Comment: @stas: And where do you think that pointer is pointing? To the bytes in the memory!

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
_buffer = &buffer;
```

is trying to assign the address of the variable `buffer` (which happens to be a pointer) into the integer variable `_buffer`.  In other words, it's assigning type "pointer to pointer" into an integer variable.  (The `&` operator means "address of.")  You probably want

```
_buffer = *buffer;
```

Which assigns the contents at the address in `buffer` (which will be an integer) to the integer `_buffer`.  The `*` operator means "contents at this address."